# Progressive MP4 video issues in Flash- Video stops rendering

Tags: flash, mp4, progressive-download

I'm currently working on a flash project that has an intro video that plays before heading into the main app.  This video is an H.264 .mp4, 1550x540, and around 10MB.

The problem thats currently driving me insane is that when I test it, occasionally the video will begin playing, and then suddenly stop rendering the video frames, leaving the audio playing in the background with nothing on screen. Once the file is played through fully (based on listening to the audio), my playback complete event fires like it should, but I can't find any info of people having similar issues.

Attached is a trace of the .mp4 metadata in case that helps.

> videoframerate : 24
>   audiochannels : 2
>   audiocodecid : mp4a
>   audiosamplerate : 48000
>   trackinfo:
>    0:
>     length : 608000
>     timescale : 24000
>     language : eng
>     sampledescription:
>      0:
>       sampletype : avc1
>    1:
>     length : 1218560
>     timescale : 48000
>     language : eng
>     sampledescription:
>      0:
>       sampletype : mp4a
>   duration : 25.386666666666667
>   width : 1540
>   videocodecid : avc1
>   seekpoints:
>    0:
>     time : 0
>     offset : 13964
>    1:
>     time : 0.333
>     offset : 16893
>    2:
>     time : 0.667
>     offset : 34212
>    ...
>    73:
>     time : 24.333
>     offset : 9770329
>    74:
>     time : 24.667
>     offset : 9845709
>    75:
>     time : 25
>     offset : 9895215
>   moovposition : 32
>   height : 540
>   avcprofile : 77
>   avclevel : 51
>   aacaot : 2

This has been driving me absolutely insane... any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out being a memory issue in Flash.